# ggplot2 and reshape2

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape

I have glad to hear that there is an updated version for reshape2 package.

I installed the package, but discovered that ggplot2 package still insist to have the reshape package, rather than the reshape2 package, as I manually removed the reshape package and then ggplot2 cannot run.

Anything I can do to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `reshape` again with `install.packages`. They won't interfere.